# How can I prevent Memory overflow in the browser when rewriting a large string very often?

Tags: javascript, typescript, string, replace, memory-leaks

Background:
I need to analyze and compare several large css.files that are generated by a less than perfect deployment process.
Before cleaning up the whole CSS-mess I need to organize the deployment process.
But simply using one consistent method of including the same files in the recommended syntax only instead of the outdated syntax mixed into, the resulting files differed vastly.
I (need to) do this in Javascript/Typescript, as the team uses webtools like this often.
The tool won't have a long shelf life and doesn't have to meet highest quality standards.
The packer generates comments with the source location of the included file, which is helpful information for our troubleshooting.

The Problem:
**The file I'm working with is 1.2 MB in size and has 34500 lines**, with 4331 comments. I parse out all the comments and store them in an array including their original starting line.
I want to get rid of the comments, as their contents might confuse the following parsing process (stray parentheses for example) but I also wanted to leave everything at its original line-position. So I **loop over the file-contents, store away one comment at a time and then I replace the comment with one or more empty lines**, depending on the number of lines the comment has.

All of this is no problem at all but for this one line:

```
this._source = this._source.replace(content, replacer);
```

this._source is the large string obviously, and content the comment, replacer the empty line(s).

The string uses up 2.5 MB of memory according to dev-tools (and being unicode internally, that seems as expected). What happens is: **with every run of the line a copy of the string is stored in memory and not garbage collected**. At about 1200 runs the memory-limit of (apparently) 4GB is reached, and in Chrome the debugger kicks in.
Firefox does not complain on my machine but ends up with a memory use of 6,5 GB.

I'm confident, that I will find a solution that is more elegant and won't have that memory issue, but I'm baffled that this happens at all. I even tried just as an experiment to stop parsing after 1000 comments, and wait 10 seconds to give the garbage collector time to free up memory, but that didn't help.

What am I doing wrong, and/or what do I not understand?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I simplified the actual code but kept the structure:
Typescript:

```
class SourceReader {
    private _fileContents: string;
    public analyzer:CSSAnalyzer;
    constructor(url: string) {
        this.loadFileContents(url);
    }

    private async loadFileContents(url:string) {
        try{
            const response = await fetch(url);
            this._fileContents = await response.text();
            this.storeFileContents();
        } catch(e){
            console.error(e);
        }
    }

    private storeFileContents = ():void => {
        this.analyzer = new CSSAnalyzer(this._fileContents);
    }
}
class CSSAnalyzer {
    private _src: string;
    private _parser:CSSFileParser;
    constructor(source: string) {
        this._src = source;
        this._parser = new CSSFileParser(this, source);
    }
}
class CSSFileParser{
    private _source:string;

    constructor(analyzer:CSSAnalyzer, source:string = '') {
    this._source = source;
    this.parse();
    
    private parse = ():void => {
        this.runTest();
    }
    private runTest = ():void => {
        if(this._source.indexOf('/*') !== -1){
            this._source = this._source.replace('/*', '');
            this.runTest();
        } else {
            console.log('runTest finished');
            console.log(this._source);
        }
    }
}
```

I still get the memory overflow.

Next Edit: With this simplified code I don't seem to have the problem in Firefox, but in chrome is persists.
And watching the Memory -tab in devtools it shows memory consumption going down after some seconds, starting with 20kb/s slowing to 1kb/s.

Next Edit:

**It took me a while to figure it out: After every near crash (the dev-tools debugger stopping the script) I had to close the current tab, as a reload even with caching disabled did not work.**

Some (final) observations:
if I cut the file roughly in half, things run with without a problem, but memory consumption in Chrome goes up to around 2 GB. Watching the Chrome-tools task-manager, only after roughly 20 idle seconds the memory is freed.
I will look for another solution now, but feel that this not the way things should work. Firefox seems to do better in this regard at least, but still consumes way to much memory in my opinion.

Comment: Your question still misses quite some context. One line of code will not provide enough information of what is going on here. Maybe you have a closure that is holding the references to the previous string and that's why it is not getting collected. You should provide more code to help us understand the issue at hand. (PS: in the last 6 months I worked on a project that loads 200.000+ lines XML file that is up to 5 MB of memory and I didn't have any GC issues).

Comment: Thank you @Elvis Adomnica. So you agree, that this accumulation can not be explained by this one line only?

Comment: I would say so. Also keep in mind that the GC has something called generations (a young generation and an old generation). The young generation is being collected quite fast but the old one takes more time because it uses a different strategy. And, if I am not mistaken, very large objects are placed in an area of memory that is collected with the same strategy as the old generation (tri-color marking and Mark-Sweep). But (refering to your other comment here), 10 seconds should be more than enough for the collector to do the work that's why I am suspecting a memory leak.

Comment: This is a good read on this closure leak subject: http://point.davidglasser.net/2013/06/27/surprising-javascript-memory-leak.html

Comment: thanks for providing more code. I think now the issue is the recursion. Can you maybe change it into  `while(this._source.indexOf('/*') !== -1){` and see if things improve?

Comment: Thank you again for the answer. I changed this to while, and in the simplified Version that helped. In the actual version I call a method of CSSFileParser to get the actual content. Doing this still works. Adding this string to an array however makes the problem reappear. Even if i don't do this, but simply ad 2 lines to calculate the line number - same effect.

Comment: then I am afraid the issue is in the "actual version" and the "simplified" one could maybe be a little too far from the actual one. Not sure why you are not sharing the actual version with some maybe edited things.